# How to find messages by text in a Dynamodb chat application?

Tags: dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index, amazon-dynamodb

I see a lot of recommendations for using dynamodb with chat applications. It is really fast when querying by keys. However a chat needs search by message text functionality which could not be implemented in dynamodb, I’m interested how other people deal with this problem ?

Comment: A on pattern is to use elasticsearch to perform full text search.  You'll often see DynamoDb streams used to update eslaticsearch indexes.

Comment: as a clarification, elastisearch is replaced with OpenSearch - but yes, the comment above still applies.

Comment: Ahh, right!  Good catch.